# Scipy -- 3d griddata -- Why is it necessary to cast griddata xi argument to tuple?

Tags: python, scipy

Why does the below call to griddata fail?

```
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
grid_vals = np.meshgrid(*([np.linspace(-1,1,200)] * 3))
interp_vals = scipy.interpolate.griddata(np.random.randn(50,3), np.random.randn(50), grid_vals, 'linear')
```

The following exception occurs:
ValueError: number of dimensions in xi does not match x

If i cast the xi (grid_vals) argument to tuple:

```
interp_vals = scipy.interpolate.griddata(np.random.randn(50,3), np.random.randn(50), tuple(grid_vals), 'linear')
```

The error goes away. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic why is that `griddata` passes both `points` and `xi` through a `points = _ndim_coords_from_arrays(points)` function whose documentation reads:

```
Convert a tuple of coordinate arrays to a (..., ndim)-shaped array.
```

and key action on tuples is:

```
p = np.broadcast_arrays(*points)
```

anything else, including a list, is just converted to an array:

```
points = np.asanyarray(points)
```

The actual interpolation expects arrays with the '3d' dimension last.

So your list of 3 `(200,200,200)` arrays becomes an array of `(3,200,200,200)` shape.  But your `points` array is `(50,3)`.  The `number of dimensions in xi does not match x` message results from `200` not matching `3`.

The `griddata` documentation is clear about `points`, less so for `xi`.  But its example uses `(x, Y)` using arrays from `mgrid`.

So this would work:

```
 X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(*([np.linspace(-1,1,200)] * 3))
 interp_vals = scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, (X,Y,Z), 'linear')
```

Another way of generating the required array from your `meshgrid` list is to make it an array, and roll the 1st dimension

```
grid_vals = np.rollaxis(np.array(grid_vals),0,4)
```

Another way of generating a mesh is `np.ix_`, which returns an open mesh in the form of  tuple.  An open mesh like this does need the broadcasting.

A single point would be interpolated with either:

```
interpolate.griddata(points,values,[[[[0,0,0]]]],'linear')
interpolate.griddata(points,values,([0],[0],[0]),'linear')
```

See the reaction to John's `4123` pull request has more discussion about the whys.

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because the underlying scipy interpolate module has code that correctly handles multi-dimensional tuples and not multi-dimensional lists:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx#L167

I've created [issue 4123](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4123) and [pull request 4124](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4124) to fix the issue, at least for lists.